# sampling algorithm - standard distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, sampling

I'm reading Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop (p526) and I've been trying to understand this:

> Suppose that $z$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0, 1)$, and
>   that we transform the values of $z$ using some function $f()$ so that $y =
>  f(z)$. The distribution of y will be governed by  $$p(y) = p(z)|{dz
>  \over dy}| $$

This doesn't make sense to me. Given the equation $y=f(z)$, we can say $p(y) = p(f(z))$. But from there I don't know how they got equation above.

Comment: This is called the transformation theorem. There are plenty of questions on this site related to it. In general, for continuous random variables you need that weird little absolute value guy. For discrete random variables, though, you don't.

Comment: @Taylor I see. I'll do some more research then. Thanks.

Comment: Start with the simplest case -- for a monotonic increasing $f$ start with $P(Y\leq y) = P(f(Z)\leq y) = P(Z\leq f^{-1}(y)) = f^{-1}(y)$. Now you have the cdf, calculate the pdf.